# Jackson polymorphism: use two mechanism at once

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to deserialize rather strange types, the type resolution can be partially solved with `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME`, but it some cases it does not fully resolve the type but narrows the selection down (meaning that two types share common value for `type` field). But these narrowed types can be resolved by present fields (using `JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION`). So I am trying to implement this logic by introducing annotating the base type for all types with `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME` and then intermediate supertype for narrowed-down types, that uses `JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION` to do the rest of the resolution.

Here is a minimalized example of what I am trying to achieve:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonTest {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "a", value = A.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "b", value = B.class),
    })
    interface Base {
        String getType();
    }

    static class A implements Base {
        private String b1;

        @Override
        public String getType() {
            return "a";
        }

        public String getB1() {
            return b1;
        }

        public A setB1(String b1) {
            this.b1 = b1;
            return this;
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B1.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B2.class),
    })
    interface B extends Base {}

    static class B1 implements B {
        private String b1;

        public String getB1() {
            return b1;
        }

        public B1 setB1(String b1) {
            this.b1 = b1;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String getType() {
            return "b";
        }
    }

    static class B2 implements B {
        private String b2;

        @Override
        public String getType() {
            return "b";
        }

        public String getB2() {
            return b2;
        }

        public B2 setB2(String b2) {
            this.b2 = b2;
            return this;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        var om = new ObjectMapper();

        var b1 = new B1();
        b1.setB1("test");

        var str = om.writeValueAsString(b1);
        System.out.println(str);

        var deser = om.readValue(str, Base.class);
        System.out.println(deser);
    }
}
```

What I get in response is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `JacksonTest$B` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 21]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1887)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:414)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1375)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:274)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:170)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:136)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:263)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4899)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3846)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3814)
    at JacksonTest.main(JacksonTest.java:87)
```

One reasonable thing to try out is to try using first deduction and then explicit type field (at least it makes sense in my case and in this simplistic case). We have to rearrange types a bit:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonTest2 {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B2.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WithB1.class),
    })
    interface Base {
        String getType();
    }


    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "a", value = A.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "b", value = B1.class),
    })
    interface WithB1 extends Base {
        String getB1();
    }

    static class A implements WithB1 {
        private String b1;

        @Override
        public String getType() {
            return "a";
        }

        public String getB1() {
            return b1;
        }

        public A setB1(String b1) {
            this.b1 = b1;
            return this;
        }
    }


    static class B1 implements WithB1 {
        private String b1;

        public String getB1() {
            return b1;
        }

        public B1 setB1(String b1) {
            this.b1 = b1;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String getType() {
            return "b";
        }
    }

    static class B2 implements Base {
        private String b2;

        @Override
        public String getType() {
            return "b";
        }

        public String getB2() {
            return b2;
        }

        public B2 setB2(String b2) {
            this.b2 = b2;
            return this;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        var om = new ObjectMapper();

        var b1 = new B1();
        b1.setB1("test");

        var str = om.writeValueAsString(b1);
        System.out.println(str);

        var deser = om.readValue(str, Base.class);

        System.out.println(deser);
    }
}
```

No luck here as well:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Subtypes JacksonTest2$A and JacksonTest2$B1 have the same signature and cannot be uniquely deduced.
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findTypeDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1834)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:675)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:5030)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4900)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3846)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3814)
    at JacksonTest2.main(JacksonTest2.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Subtypes JacksonTest2$A and JacksonTest2$B1 have the same signature and cannot be uniquely deduced.
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.buildFingerprints(AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.java:90)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.<init>(AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.java:49)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.StdTypeResolverBuilder.buildTypeDeserializer(StdTypeResolverBuilder.java:212)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findTypeDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1832)
    ... 6 more
```

Is this achievable with Jackson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself.

tl;dr: Just avoid doing that: introduce some extra type info if this is data produced by you or try to convince the data supplier to do so.

Seems like there is no simple and out-of-the-box way to do it.

I ended up getting rid of artificial class hiererchy, and attaching custom `@JsonTypeResolver` to your class and implementing this resolver myself. Attaching `@JsonTypeIdResolver` is not enough, because deduction mechanism lives above it.

Here are the annotations on the base interface:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "a", value = A.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "b", value = B1.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "b", value = B2.class),
})
```

Implementing `TypeDeserializer` involves extending one of standard Jackson `TypeDeserializer`s and just monkey-patching it.

The first intention is to group `subtypes` passed to `TypeResolverBuilder.buildTypeDeserializer` by their id, pass them to `TypeDeserializer` and let it delegate to `AsDeductionTypeDeserializer` when the type id is not unique. One more caveat is that `subtypes` passed to `StdTypeResolverBuilder.buildTypeDeserializer` will never have types with duplicate ids, standard `SubtypeResolver` just removes duplicates. You can also patch it to use in your custom `TypeResolverBuilder`.

So, here are monkey-patched classes you need:

- `TypeResolverBuilder` that you will attach to your class using the annotation and that returns custom `TypeDeserializer`
- `TypeDeserializer` itself, which will delegate type deserialization to `AsDeductionTypeDeserializer` using narrowed-down list of subtypes
- `SubtypeResolver` that allows duplicates returned from `collectAndResolveSubtypesByTypeId`

The complete answer is quite big for the answer, so I shared it using [gist](https://gist.github.com/gagarski/c08566f6ed850f98d1c4b2d289d5b230)